# Asp.Net Treeview control collapsed does not select the child checkbox. How to handle this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, treeview

I have a ASP.NET treeview control which has checkboxes.

Using this jQuery to check all the child checkboxes when parent is checked. This code works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     function CheckboxGroupSelection() { 
         $('.tree :checkbox').on('change', function () {
             var checked = this.checked;

             var $elem = $(this).closest('table');
             var depth = $elem.find('div').length;
             var $childs = $elem.nextAll('table');
             $childs.each(function () {
                 var $child = $(this);
                 var d = $child.find('div').length;
                 if (d == depth) {
                     return false;
                 }
                 $child.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
             });
         }); 
     }
</script>
```

Now, the problem is here: when the parent node is collapsed and then check the parent node checkbox, logically all the child checkboxes should be selected. But this jQuery cannot be used for doing that, as there jQuery uses the HTML markup to find and check the checkboxes,  and, when the parent node is collapsed, I could not see the child node markup.

How to handle this ? Or Is this there any way to achieve this using codebehind either c# or vb.net ?

HTML markup when collapsed :

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" class="tree" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$Treecontrol_Left_0$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Clinics" src="../Uploadedimages/System/Static_Images/TreeLineImages/dashminus.gif"></a></td><td style="width:295px;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><span style="text-decoration:none;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext0">Clinics</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$Treecontrol_Left_0$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\726a5894-6495-4bd2-90fa-1c0eb60f9406')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Expand GP Clinics" src="../Uploadedimages/System/Static_Images/TreeLineImages/tplus.gif"></a></td><td style="width:295px;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><span style="text-decoration:none;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext1">GP Clinics</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="../Uploadedimages/System/Static_Images/TreeLineImages/t.gif"></td><td style="width:295px;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><span style="text-decoration:none;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext7">Other Clinics</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="../Uploadedimages/System/Static_Images/TreeLineImages/l.gif"></td><td style="width:295px;"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox"><span style="text-decoration:none;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext8">Polyclinics</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create fiddle for this. When CheckboxGroupSelection() function is called?

Comment: @Anjith http://jsfiddle.net/srk1982/GhFSV/

Comment: how did u collapsing parent nodes?

Comment: @Anjith I am using the asp.net treeview control. And it take care of collapse and expand. I just put the HTML which is rendered in browser. When collapse, there are no child elements in the HTML markup. The Markup i used in fiddle is the one with all nodes expanded

Comment: can you provide html structure of one collapsed node

Comment: @Anjith Updated the question HTML markup when collapsed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31456/discussion-between-anjith-and-anuya)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub tree_TreeNodeCheckChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeEventArgs) 
    If e IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Node IsNot Nothing Then 
        If e.Node.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
            CheckTreeNodeRecursive(e.Node, e.Node.Checked)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckTreeNodeRecursive(ByVal parent As TreeNode, ByVal fCheck As Boolean) 
    For Each child As TreeNode In parent.ChildNodes

        If child.Checked <> fCheck Then
            child.Checked = fCheck
        End If

        If child.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
            CheckTreeNodeRecursive(child, fCheck)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```